# Cross referencing between chapters in thesis (LaTex)

Tags: cross-referencing, thesis, back-referencing

I am writing a thesis. While writing chapter 3, I need to refer an equation from chapter 2. How could I do this? I do not want to repeat the same equation in every chapter. Kindly help. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: what did you try, it should just work with no special code, `\label{foo}` on the equation and `\ref{foo}` to refer to it, the chapter structure does not affect this at all.

Comment: For equations, you might try `\eqref{foo}`.

Comment: Assuming you already know about `\label` and `\ref`, does your question mean that you *do* want to repeat the equation, with the same number, but without retyping it?

Answer (score 1):

There are several packages that would do the job. I would recommend to use the `hyperref` package in combination with the `cleveref` package. `hyperref` should be loaded last and `cleveref` afterwards. The former one enables the base functionality for hyperlinks and the latter one extends it (it automatically determines the type of the referenced object and will precede the number accordingly with equation, table, figure). Then assuming you labeled your equation you can simply reference it with `\cref{eq:label_of_equation}`. The `eq:` is not mandatory but it helps in keeping the overview.